# how to move between views by using Tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbar

I am doing an application  which is of SingleView BASED Application,where i have many UIviewcontrollerclass subclasses for moving from one view to another view.i have a tab bar in one of the view and want to communicate with others view when click on a tab.so plz tell me how can i do it i am stuck here.
i have classes called

LoginPage.h/.m/.xib

Myservices.h/.m/.xib

History.h/.m/.xib

Profile.h/.m/.xib

MyRecentRequest.h/.m/.xib

when i enter from login page it moves to Myservices view.
There i have added Tab bar at the bottom and added two more tab Items and totally have 4 tab bar items naming Myservices,history,MyrecentRequest and profile.

Now i want to connect the tab bar with other class so that when i click on tab  item respective view should appear of that particular classs so how can i do this? please provide me sample code.

Comment: is there a reason you aren't using a UITabBarController to hold the MyServices History, Profile and MyRecentRequests view controllers? While not logged in you can add the LoginPage view (or a navigation controller holding it) to the application window. After logging in you can remove the LoginPage and add the tab controller.

Comment: @babbidi i am not using UItab controller because i want this only for 3 views.And my application doent have only these views i have more views so flow from from one screen to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all how u r maintaining the tabBar, either from IB or code. The below if by code. You need to alloc a tabBar with all the viewControllers required into each tabItem, the below one is sample with 2 tabItems:

```
UITabBarController* tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];

ViewController1* vC1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
UINavigationController* navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vC1];
[vC1 release];      
navController1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navController1_image.png"];
[localViewControllersArray addObject:navController1];
[navController1 release]; 

ViewController2* vC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
UINavigationController* navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vC2];
navController2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navController2_image.png"];
[vC2 release];      
[localViewControllersArray addObject:navController2];
[navController2 release]; 

tabBarController.viewControllers = localViewControllersArray;
    self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;
[localViewControllersArray release];
    [tabBarController release];
```

In this way u can maintain the tabBar by code, so that if tab is selected respective view will be shown, in this example a navigation controller is used in each tab to provide navigation, if only 1 view is required u can avoid the navigation controller..

Comment: i am maintaining Tabbar by IB..i h ave a dragged a tab bar from library?with 4 tab bar items..

Comment: it will be better if u go by code, cause after sign in u can call a method to alloc tabBar,initialize and add to window. After logout remove tabBar,release and show the login screen. It will be easy to maintain..

Comment: but i am using tab bar for only these screen... again from my service view the views will continue to move further without tab bar?so wat should i do?

Comment: then its better to implement with code, when exiting from tabBar release it. implement the methods in appDelegate. cause if its used for only at some instance then why to hold from IB.

Comment: so above code where i should add or in which method??do i need to drag tabBar from library and connect any IBoutlet?please guide me na can we continue discussion in chat?

Comment: ok.. show me the code of didFinishLaunching... start up details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7192/discussion-between-crazy2431-and-vishy)

Answer (score 1):

For that the following code is use to dynamically select the navigation controller and select the which tab is select.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
tabBarController.delegate=self;
tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];

mainDashBoard=[[DashBoard alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashBoard" bundle:nil];
mainSearchView=[[SearchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle:nil];
mainMoreView=[[MoreView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreView" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *nvCtr0=[[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nvCtr1=[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainDashBoard] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nvCtr2=[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainSearchView] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nvCtr3=[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMoreView] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nvCtr4=[[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];//[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nil] autorelease];

tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nvCtr0,nvCtr1,nvCtr2,nvCtr3,nvCtr4,nil];

nvCtr0.tabBarItem.enabled=NO;
nvCtr4.tabBarItem.enabled=NO;
 delegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
[window tabBarController.view];
}
```

this may be helpful to crate the application